# Using .crt and .key files to set up a Vert.x SSL server written in Java

Tags: java, vert.x

I found an example of setting up a Vert.x SSL server written in Java using .jks file here:  http://vertx.io/core_manual_java.html#ssl-servers.

```
NetServer server = vertx.createNetServer()
           .setSSL(true)
           .setKeyStorePath("/path/to/your/keystore/server-keystore.jks")
           .setKeyStorePassword("password");
```

Does anyone know how to set up a Vert.x SSL server written in Java using .crt and .key files directly without converting them to .jks file?

Comment: i'm pretty sure david is right. but you can use: http://www.agentbob.info/agentbob/79-AB.html
Download the converter (put them in .pem format first)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible.

Just create a new keystore and import the key and CRT in it.

Comment: Why isn't it possible? Just how?